# After clicking backspace button text starts from the beginning of a textbox

Tags: vb.net, backspace

The button works but after it is pressed the text needs to start when it was left off and not in the beginning.

```
 '' Button to remove 1 number
Private Sub btnCE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCE.Click
    If pinbox.Text.Count > 0 Then '' Works if count is bigger then 0
        pinbox.Text = pinbox.Text.Remove(pinbox.Text.Count - 1) '' Remove 1 number
    End If
```

Here is a visual representation of the problem

[image]

And yes i am aware that CE is the wrong term used and i will change it :(

Comment: How are you adding the 7 into the textbox can you show that code?

Comment: Is this handler executed when the user clicks a number?

Comment: @Scath https://gyazo.com/47d7606c2e9648e625e5fd91d83f2a71

Comment: @TimSchmelter This code is executed when the user clicks this specific button if thats what you mean.

Comment: @Michalodzien: you know that you can use one handler for all buttons because the code is same? Cast the sender argument to `Button`: `pinbox.SelectedText = pinbox.SelectedText + CType(sender, Button).Text `

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will try this to make it simpler, thanks! I still need to get this backspace button to work correctly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing this line in each number:

```
pinbox.Text= btn7.Text
```

To:

```
pinbox.Text= pinbox.Text + btn7.Text
```

Should put the new text at the end of the `pinbox`.

Comment: Try that I am not sure what SelectedText is is pinbox a regular textbox?

Comment: Yes it is a regular textbox

Comment: I am thinking if there is code that can just select the space after the last number and i can just write it in on all the numbers?

Comment: Hey nevermind your code actually worked, i just didn't see that you edited it. Thanks a ton.